# ODE Solving in Scilab

Tags: ode, scilab

I have a certain ODE problem that needs to be solved using Scilab.

```
dx(1)/dt=k*x(1)-x(5)
dx(2)/dt=k2*x(2)-k1*x(1)
dx(3)/dt=k1*[x(2)-x(3)]
dx(4)/dt=k1*[x(3)-x(4)]
```

`x(5)` takes value `0` till time `t0`

Can anyone help me with coding this problem? Any suggestions would be of immense help.

Comment: welcome to SciComp. Please first check the help of Scilab itself (http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/ode.html). And you should at least specify your initial conditions.

Comment: no information about the rate of change of x(5)? what does happen to x(5) after time > t0?

Comment: no but x(5) with respect to time t would be provided.

Comment: yes the initial conditions would be provided ofcourse.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by GertVdE, you can use [ODE](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.2/en_US/ode.html) function in scilab, 
or refer the following document,

[Ordinary Differential Equations with SCILAB](http://www.infoclearinghouse.com/files/scilab/scilab09.pdf), written by Gilberto E. Urroz discusses various ODE's, their types and their solution with SCILAB,

on page 45, you might an answer to your question.